# ArgumentException on navigation property query in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following LINQ query in a Visual Studio 2015 WPF app using Entity Framework 6:

```
var query = Context.Services.AsQueryable();
```

The `Services` entity has the following navigation property:

```
public virtual ICollection<ServiceStatu> ServiceStatus { get; set; }
```

A Service can have 0 or many ServiceStatus. I'm trying to use `Include` to fetch services with status that equal 7:

```
query = query.Include(x => x.ServiceStatus.Where(p => p.serviceStatusID == 7));
```

But it's throwing this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Note that I had tried doing this using `JOIN`s but that was ugly, so I decided to use the built-in nav properties.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `Include` is for eagerly loading everything. It can't contain filters (`Where`).

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev. So how would I fix this to reference the nav property and filter on it?

Comment: Put the `where` after the `include` method call, not inside.

Comment: If you just want to get sevices with status 7, then you can use `var query = Context.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceStatus.Any(s => s.serviceStatusID == 7))`

Comment: I'm doing stuff with the Services entity (not in my code above) and then adding this to that query

Comment: Navigation properties has dual purpose. Inside query, they are used just as metadata to produce the necessary joins. For materialized entities they contain the related entities (when loaded - either eager or lazy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Where` on `Include` statements, apply any the filter after the `Include`.

You can disable *Lazy Loading* in the Context constructor:

```
class EfContext : DbContext
{
    public EfContext()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    ...
```

Then, if you have defined a `ServiceId` property in `ServiceStatu` Model:

```
Service service = ...;
context.ServiceStatus.Where(s => ServiceId == service.Id).Load()
```

or

```
context.Entry(service).Collection(s => s.ServiceStatu).Load()
```

But as soon you load another `ServiceStatu` belonging to that `service`, **EF** will add it to the collection of the `service`.

In your case you can use *Lazy Load* and project the results or filter the status and store it in another variable:

```
var newQuery = query.Select(s => new { Service = s, FilteredStatus = s.ServiceStatu.Where(ss => ss.ServiceStatusID == 7) });

//or

var status = service.ServiceStatu.Where(s => s.ServiceStatusID == 7);
```

Comment: Using your first code sample, it's telling me `'Services' does not contain a definition for 'serviceStatusID'` and so it won't compile

Comment: @Alex: sorry, I forgot `ServiceStatus` property

Comment: Now it's saying `'ServiceStatu' does not contain a definition for 'serviceStatusID'`. Note the spelling of `ServiceStatu`

Comment: @Alex: Oh, I see now, i going to update my answer, but you cant load only certains status, at least in lazy loading

Comment: Thanks, @ArturoMenchaca. How can I make it eager loading then?

Comment: @Alex: Remove `virtual` modifier from `ServiceStatu` property

Comment: If I don't remove the `virtual` modifier, is there a way to get your first example working? I'm using auto-generated models in EF so I hate to modify them. Thanks, @ArturoMenchaca.

Comment: Even with the removal of `virtual` it still blew up with the same error.

Comment: Yes, i'm updating my answer, but that error was because I thought ServiceStatu was not a collection.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't filter the navigation property in an `Include` call. As the exception said you need to refer a navigation property. To filter your navigation property you will need to project your query to a anonymous type or a DTO, eg:

```
query = query.Include(x => x.ServiceStatus)
             .Select(s=>new {
                              //other properties that you need to project
                              Status=s.ServicesStatus.Where(p => p.serviceStatusID == 7)
                            });
```

One way to filter the related entity at the time it is loaded is using [Explicit Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit):

```
 var service= query.FistOrDefault();// this is an example to use a service instance
 context.Entry(service) 
        .Collection(b => b.ServiceStatus) 
        .Query() 
        .Where(ss => ss.Where(p => p.serviceStatusID == 7) 
        .Load();
```

Comment: Thanks, @octavioccl. The first example gives error saying it can't implicitly convert ServiceStatus to Services; my query is created on the Services and I run other `Where` clauses on it before getting to this point.

Comment: Could you publish you entire query to see more details what are you doing?