# Entity Framework query exception when looking for an entity contained in a collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm running the query below to obtain all the events (as a registered student) I'm attending on a specific day and getting an error that says

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'YogaBandy.Models.Profile.YogaProfile'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Here is the query I'm using to get all events I'm regsitered for on a specific day.

```
// my profile
var yogaProfile = dbContext.YogaProfiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == userId).First();
// events I'm registered for on a specific day
var eventsNew = dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(
                i => i.EventDateTime.Day == date.Day
                && i.EventStatus == YogaSpaceEventStatus.Active
                && i.RegisteredStudentsNew.Contains(yogaProfile)).ToList();
```

I think it might have something to do with part, but not sure

> && i.RegisteredStudentsNew.Contains(yogaProfile)

FYI - my RegisteredStudentsNew looks like this in the 'YogaSpaceEvents' entity

```
public virtual ICollection<YogaProfile> RegisteredStudentsNew { get; set; }
```

and when I add a newly regsitered student I add him/her like this

```
spaceEvent.RegisteredStudentsNew.Add(yogaProfile);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `i.RegisteredStudentsNew.Contains(yogaProfile)` looks suspicious

Comment: You cannot use a complex object in `.Contains`

Comment: so then how do I search for what I need?

Comment: It seems like it should accept a YogaProfile in the contains, because when I hover over the .Contains method I see 'Models.Profile.YogaProfile' and that's what I'm passing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `YogaProfiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == userId)` inside `Include` statement.

**Example:**

```
var eventsNew = dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents
.Include(p=>p.RegisteredStudentsNew.Where(rp => rp.ApplicationUserId == userId))
.Where( i => i.EventDateTime.Day == date.Day 
        && i.EventStatus == YogaSpaceEventStatus.Active)
        .ToList();
```

**OR**
use `Any` in your `where` clause

```
var eventsNew = dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents
                .Include(p=>p.RegisteredStudentsNew)
                .Where(i => i.EventDateTime.Day == date.Day
                && i.EventStatus == YogaSpaceEventStatus.Active
                && i.RegisteredStudentsNew.Any(rp => rp.ApplicationUserId == userId))
                .ToList();
```

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685069/c-sharp-linq-include-before-after-where) for why use `Include` in LINQ.

Comment: hi. I ran your first example but got teh exception "System.ArgumentException: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path"

Comment: @user1186050 are you try both or first one?Please use second one.

Comment: @user1186050 please read this answer why you can't use first one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202853/argumentexception-on-navigation-property-query-in-linq

Comment: Ashiquzzaman - I think there is a problem with the way I'm adding a YogaProfile to a RegisteredStudentNew Virtual ICollection. The column that was created when I added this, 'YogaSpaceEvent_YogaSpaceEventId' in the YogaProfile table only holds a single int value. So if I add a profile, it saves it fine ex. 1234, but when I go to add another profile it overwrites the first value 1234 with a new value of 4567. So when I search, according to your quesry, I will always receive just 1 returned profile.

Comment: FYI - this has to be a collection of YogaProfiles, hence registeredstudentsnew (plural) and when I look at the migration file it shows the column as a int